# Refresh C# listbox when change in Loaded Text file

Tags: c#, file, text, listbox, serial-port

Ok I know similar questions have been asked, But I am trying to have a Listbox monitor a text file that is changed by another program.  I have it setup to select the top line in the file, and execute a command based off that line, then it deletes top line.  I just need the listbox to refresh after deletion and read new top line and continue to read until null.  I am also having it monitor if the serialPort is OPEN or not.  ( I want it to only loop if the serial Port is closed).  I am fairly new to C# so any help is appreciated. My current code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    List<string> myList = new List<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myList = System.IO.File.ReadLines("textfile").ToList();

        this.GPSCOM.DataSource = myList;
        GPSCOM.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
        myList.FirstOrDefault();
        GPSCOM.SetSelected(0, true);
         if (serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
             for(;;)
             {
                 switch ((string)GPSCOM.SelectedItem)
                 {
                     case "set1":
                         var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("textfile");
                         System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("textfile", lines.Skip(1).ToArray());
                         return;
                     case "set2":
                         var lines1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("textfile");
                         System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("textfile", lines1.Skip(1).ToArray());

                         return;
                     case "set3":

                         var lines2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("textfile");
                         System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("textfile", lines2.Skip(1).ToArray());
                         return;
                 }
            }
         }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A FileSystemWatcher would be your best bet.

I would like to ask however if it would be inconvenient to make the other program output to its standard output stream and use ProcessStartInfo in System.Diagnosics to redirect the output. If would be a faster and more direct solution as the data could be moved directly between the two programs instead of using the less indirect file storage method. Cut out the middle man as it were.

Comment: I plan on it, but the textfile is only to update the listbox and tell this program what program to run next.  The textfile in this case is actually originally created by an ASP.net website.  I am trying to actually create a monitoring program that logs request from the website(its intranet)  and triggers the appropriate program or response on the server.

Comment: In that case it might be better to look into some of the System.Net classes such as sockets or http listeners. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net(v=vs.100).aspx) Though it depends if the programs are running on the same machine or not. If this is a case of server communicating to client, System.Net is your best bet for a solution.

Comment: can I just add FileSystemWatcher in the properties modify the filter and path to match file, I want it to monitor. and then in the FileSystemWatcher_Changed code it to refresh the listbox?

Comment: Yes, for the purpose of your current set-up, creating an event handler for a file system watcher would be your best option.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) and catching the change notification than continuously polling the contents of the file.

Comment: Thanks, Ill look into how I can do this properly.  I know I probably need to Bind it as well.